# Как в VS Code сделать так, что бы он перестал следить за проектом через GitHub?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня следующая проблема в которой я не могу разобраться:

В общем, у меня почему то не верно собирался Галп и я решил скинуть весь свой проект другу, что бы он посмотрел.
Создал репозиторий на GitHub, сохранил через VS Code и теперь хочу что бы VS Code перестал следить за изменениями ,так как друг уже всё посмотрел.
Я удалил на GitHub репозиторий, удалил папку с рабочего стола с наименованием Git, удалил какой то файл с названием git и всё равно у меня выскакивают не сохраненные изменения...
А я хочу просто дальше пытаться по видео собирать сборку gulp и что бы не выскакивали сообщения об изменениях.

В общем вопрос в том, что я хочу **удалить репозиторий** -> и что бы **vs code перестал следить за ним**, а я дальше **продолжил работать с проектом** (как если бы не сохранял его в GitHub)

Помогите, прошу Вас, как это решить?

Comment: Не понятно, что подразумевается под "vs code следит за проектом через GitHub". Я предполагаю, что у вас просто гит репозиторий, и vscode подсвечивает незакоммиченные изменения. Чтобы папка перестала быть git репозиторием, нужно просто удалить папку `.git` в ней. Хотя работать над проектом без гита - так себе идея.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего у вас осталась директория .git
Удалите ее любым удобным способом.

Можно сделать так:

- Откройке свой проект в VSCode
- Откройте терминал встроенный в VSCode
- Выполните `ls -а` чтобы посмотреть все файлы файлы в директории
- Если в списке будет директория .git то просто выполните `rm -rf .git`

Answer (score 1):

Зайдите в настройки в Vs code(шестерёнка в нижнем левом углу) ->параметры ->Вкладка рабочая область или конкретную папку можно выбрать. В открывшемся окне в боковой панели слева откройте 'расширения', и выберите git.Теперь в правой панели настроек Найдите Auto Repository Detection, установите false. И проект нужно обернуть ещё в одну папку, т.к при false vs не будет сканировать subfolders